# Error type is a string but server sends a json object describing the error Angular8

Tags: angular

API sends an error as a response like this

```
    "errors": {
        "Password": [
            "The Password field is required.",
            "You must specify password between 4 and 8 character"
        ],
        "Username": [
            "The Username field is required."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "0HLPRA2KJHLQD:00000001"
}
```

I have an error interseptor implemented in the app

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    return throwError(error.statusText);
                }
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
                    if (applicationError) {
                        console.error(applicationError);
                        return throwError(applicationError);
                    }
                    const serverError = error.error;
                    let modalStateErrors = '';
                    if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object') {
                        for (const key in server errorserverError) {
                            if (serverError[key]) {
                                modalStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || 'Server Error');
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Code to call the api

```
 register() {
    this.authService.register(this.model).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('registration successful');
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

so the problem is error object that I am trying to print is a string type and I lose the value for errors object mentioned in the JSON above, as a result, I cannot deduce what error that actually occurred. So how can I receive error object as JSON

Answer (score 0):

changed http interceptor to

```
 let modalStateErrors = '';
                    if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object' && serverError.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
                        for (const key in serverError.errors) {
                            if (serverError.errors[key]) {
                                modalStateErrors += serverError.errors[key] + '\n';
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

It worked